# List users who have become root via "su" in last 30 days

Tags: root, command-history, su

How do I get the history of the users who have used `su` command to become `root` in Linux (in my specific case SuSe)?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why `su` hasn't been used for decades - no logging. Use `sudo` instead. Read `man sudo sudoers`. The command history is saved in `~/.history` by default (check shell startup files,  `~/.bashrc`), and is overwritten every session. You can search `/var/log/*` for `"su"` to see that `su` was used, but you can't see what was done.

Comment: Check /var/log/auth.log*

Answer (score 3):

@Eduardo Trapani's comment is on the right track.  Search `/var/log/auth.log` for whole-word occurrences of `su(1)`:

```
# grep -w su /var/log/auth.log
Jun  9 23:33:47 <auth.notice> jimsdesk su[30048]: jim to root on /dev/pts/0
```

The above example indicates that user `jim` became `root` on Jun  9 at 23:33:47.

If you want to know what actual commands were performed, you should either implement @waltinator's suggestion of using `sudo(8)` or else hope that `/root/.history` or similar history file hasn't been overwritten or bypassed.  Regardless, `root`'s history file isn't going help sort out who did what (if that is an issue), in cases where `sudo` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

@Jim L. [is on the right track](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653632/106650) :)

On a modern Linux, you'd typically not have an actively kept /var/log/auth.log, though. Instead, the same idea, but with `journalctl`:

```
journalctl --since=2021-05-09
```

You need to make journalctl quiet (-q) and make it only print successful authentications for su:

```
journalctl --since=2021-05-09 -q -g 'pam_unix\(su:session\): session opened for user root'
```

If we only care about the number of these:

```
journalctl --since=2021-05-09 -q -g 'pam_unix\(su:session\): session opened for user root' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim.  It worked.

Comment: I'm not Jim, but I'm happy it worked nevertheless!